# WP-ADMIN Redirect Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, nginx

We have a multisite running with about 6 sites.

3 of our sites are accessible through the wp-admin the other 3 aren't.

The browsers tells us that there are too many redirects going on. This only happens after we log in to the wp-admin. The wp-login page works fine.

We've had this issue before, solved the now working 3 sites with the following fix in our `wp-config`:

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```

Also the front-end is working just fine, it's only the wp-admin having issues.

**Background information:**
**Server**: Nginx + Apache. Starts at Nginx but then redirects to Apache
**SSL**: enabled

Comment: More information is needed - are they all running the same plugins, theme etc? There is something different between the site setups, you have to find out what that is. Unfortunately nobody here will be able to help with that without more information.

Comment: @markmoxx Yeah they are running the same plugins, themes are different though

Comment: You edited to say that you fixed the three working sites before - were they all acting the same, so if you switched HTTPS on for  the other three, it would fix?

Comment: Your best bet is to clone the multisite to a staging environment, check it happens there, and switch the themes to see if it's the theme which is causing the issue.

Comment: They all had the redirect issue before, after adding the HTTPS it fixed three of them

Comment: Did you end up resolving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the codex:

> If WordPress is hosted behind a reverse proxy that provides SSL, but
>   is hosted itself without SSL, these options will initially send any
>   requests into an infinite redirect loop. To avoid this, you may
>   configure WordPress to recognize the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO header
>   (assuming you have properly configured the reverse proxy to set that
>   header).

The following actions will solve the problem.

Add this to wp-config.php. ([codex reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL))

```
/* SSL Settings */
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);

/* Turn HTTPS 'on' if HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO matches 'https' */
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
```

[Reference](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250240/setting-serverhttps-on-prevents-access-to-wp-admin)

Comment: If I add this in the wp-config, we get a redirect loop everywhere

Comment: We already put `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';` in `wp-config.php`, we don't need to optionally also allow http traffic.

This doesn't fix it either: `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);`

Comment: Also the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` header returns `https` in our case

Comment: thanks this has really fixed my issue!! I'm using wordpress in a sub-domain routed with cloudflare.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and could solve it. The problem was my admin user's capabilities were set to subscriber instead of administrator. Probably from a membership plugin.

In my database table wp_usermeta my admin-users 
wp_capabilities were set to "a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}"

I change it to "a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}" and I saw my Dashboard again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case where I have the nginx ingress controller as a reverse proxy in kubernetes cluster where it do a TLS termination and wordpress instancess in pods served by http protocol and nginx instead apache engine, the redirection loop happens when I had in the `location / {...}` block `try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;` instead `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;`